# Check if certain value is contained in a dataframe column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to check if a certain value is contained in a python column. I'm using `df.date.isin(['07311954'])`, which I do not doubt to be a good tool. The problem is that I have over 350K rows and the output won't show 
all of them so that I can see if the value is actually contained. Put simply, I just want to know (Y/N) whether or not a specific value is contained in a column. My code follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob


df = (pd.read_csv('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/FEC_data/itpas2_data/itpas214.txt',\
    sep='|', header=None, low_memory=False, names=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', \
    '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', 'date', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', \
    '21', '22']))

df.date.isin(['07311954'])
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you need [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), if you need rows where values of column `date` contains string `07311954`:

```
print df[df['date'].astype(str).str.contains('07311954')]
```

Or if `type` of `date` column is `string`:

```
print df[df['date'].str.contains('07311954')]
```

If you want check last 4 digits for `string` `1954` in column `date`:

```
print df[df['date'].astype(str).str[-4:].str.contains('1954')]
```

Sample:

```
print df['date']
0    8152007
1    9262007
2    7311954
3    2252011
4    2012011
5    2012011
6    2222011
7    2282011
Name: date, dtype: int64

print df['date'].astype(str).str[-4:].str.contains('1954')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: date, dtype: bool

print df[df['date'].astype(str).str[-4:].str.contains('1954')]
     cmte_id trans_typ entity_typ state  employer  occupation     date  \
2  C00119040       24K        CCM    MD       NaN         NaN  7311954   

   amount     fec_id    cand_id  
2    1000  C00140715  H2MD05155
```

Comment: I think you, I ran your suggested code and I still get a very long and incomplete list.

Comment: I just ran it, I was having some syntax errors earlier so stopped for a break. When I run the code above it points out the 1954 date; but when I run the code on the same data set after having after having implemented (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939558/using-timegrouper-1m-to-group-and-sum-by-columns-is-messing-up-my-date-index-p/35957110#35957110) it returns  'Empty DataFrame
Columns: [cmte_id, trans_typ, entity_typ, state, date, amount, fec_id, cand_id]
Index: []`

Comment: Jezrael, I'm going to look through the data files again and see just how many files have the date column market with a date that is "out of range". Theoretically, all of my dates should be between 2007 and 2014. Is there a way to use the code that you have posted above but print all values with the last 4 digits between 2007 and 2014? I would also like to delete all rows that occur as such, but first I need to locate them so I can inform the data source of the error in the data. If you can help me with that it would be great!

Comment: Please check [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35958541/2901002), there was problem with parse column `date` to `datetime`.

Comment: Are you able to put a list in there so you can check multiple values at once?

Comment: @GaryDorman - yes, then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577689/2901002) solution

Answer (score 64):

You can simply use this:

`'07311954' in df.date.values` which returns `True` or `False`

---

Here is the further explanation:

In pandas, using `in` check directly with DataFrame and Series (e.g. `val in df` or `val in series` ) will check whether the `val` is contained in the **Index**.

BUT you can still use `in` check for their values too (instead of Index)! Just using `val in df.col_name.values`
or `val in series.values`. In this way, you are actually checking the `val` with a Numpy array.

And `.isin(vals)` is the other way around, it checks whether the DataFrame/Series values *are in* the `vals`. Here `vals` must be **set or list-like**. So this is not the natural way to go for the question.

Answer (score 32):

You can use `any`:

```
print any(df.column == 07311954)
True       #true if it contains the number, false otherwise
```

If you rather want to see how many times *'07311954'* occurs in a column you can use:

```
df.column[df.column == 07311954].count()
```