# Trying to look for a value in the whole column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've tried the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

excel_file = 'bank_acc.xlsx'
bank_acc = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
bank_acc.describe()
acc_no = 1
column1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, index_cols=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A:C", skiprows=0)
if acc_no in column1:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

But it is always printing `"not found"`

I have the following excel file:

[image: Excel file]

now if i change the value of acc_no as 1 , 2 or 3 it prints the not found.
if i change the values of acc_no from as string 'acc_no' then it print found.
i think it means that it only scan the first row always...not  all rows..
can anyone have a suggestion or i have written a wrong code...

Comment: Edit the question to show the full error message (traceback).

Comment: @MichaelButscher What error? OP says it is printing "not found" always

Comment: yes it print always not found. if i am enter 2 it print not found. if i change acc_no='acc_no' then it says found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if certain value is contained in a dataframe column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956712/check-if-certain-value-is-contained-in-a-dataframe-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my way. I had to remove my old answer since I spotted a few mistakes.
This should work.

```
    df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
    print(df)
    acc_no = 3  # you can change this value
    a = any(df['acc_no'] == acc_no)
    if a == True:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```