# Finding a whether a value exits in Pandas dataframe column using 'in' not working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently writing a script to filter csv output data from cycles of an automated machine. What I want is to provide indexes of the start and stop of a cycle and check if the machine 'state' column contains an int value 12. I am looking at the first two cycles and running the exact same code but different indexes for the smaller L dataframe.  For the first cycle [0:16], v returns true as expected.  However, the second cycle returns v as False even though the state column contains 12.  The goal is to eventually find the indexes of every cycle (when key == 102) in a list and loop through to find out if state 12 executed or not in every cycle.

Here is a snapshot of the dataframe first cycle:
[first cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvGxS.png)

Here is a snapshot of the first half of the second cycle:
[second cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT9d7.png)

Both dataframe have a value of 12 in the state column.  So it should return True if I use 'in'.

```
L = df[0:16]

#exists = 12 in L.state

v = 12 in L.state
print(v)
```

The above returns True as expected.

```
L = df[16:51]

#exists = 12 in L.state

v = 12 in L.state
print(v)
```

The above returns False which is confusing me.

Since the same dataframe is used to make the smaller L dataframe and the same 12 in L.state call to return a bool.  Does anyone know what I missing as to why is this code executing differently on the second set of indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you use `in` to make a comparison in a series, it is checking index. If you want to check for values, use `v = 12 in L.state.values`. I saw this answer in a related SO comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40419531/14473410

Comment: Oh no wonder.  Thank you ;)